# Implementing Search module in SDL DXA 2 and integrate it with Apache Solr

Tags: dxa, si4t, solr, dxa-2.0

While trying to implement Search module in SDL DXA 2 and integrate it with Apache Solr, we are getting the below logs in SI4T.

```
2018-03-08 11:19:19,211 INFO  TridionPublishableItemProcessor - Finding search directives.
2018-03-08 11:19:19,212 INFO  TridionPublishableItemProcessor - No search data found.
```

Not sure if it is because Metadata Schema is selected as "Component Template Metadata" instead of "Search Indexing Metadata".

Any thoughts on resolving this error or how to add "Search Indexing Metadata" to "Metadata Schema" of a component template which already has "Component Template Metadata" as the metadata schema in SDL DXA 2.0
Right now we are not able to add this because "Metadata Schema" is a dropdown and it already has "Component Template Metadata".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can create the **"Search Indexing TBB Parameters" Schema** instead of **"Search Indexing Metadata" Schema** and then Link it with "**Generate Index Data**" TBB as Parameters Schema.

[Example TBB Parameters Schema](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/master/tbbs/xsd/Search%20Indexing%20Template%20Metadata.xsd)

[image]

In the Page Template while Adding the **Generate Index Data** TBB select and provide the Including/Excluding individual component fields values.

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. When I published a page which has binary in it, from the logs we found that everytime the binary processes first and that doesn't have any info on the actual page it is residing. We actually wanted to index the residing page url as well. If you can guide me on this.. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate all the fields from one metadata schema (Search Indexing Metadata) in the other (Component Template Metadata).